# This short AppleScript using weekday is not working as expected

Tags: applescript

```
set currentDay to weekday of (get current date)

if currentDay = "Monday" or currentDay = "Tuesday" or currentDay = "Wednesday" then
    set earlymorningDisc to 1
else if currentDay = "Thursday" or currentDay = "Friday" then
    set earlymorningDisc to 2
else
    set earlymorningDisc to 3
end if
```

It is always setting early morning disc to 3. I am new to mac and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: @Tetsujin Ah, and printing/inspecting the variable will probably just return `Friday`, as would printing the string. Tricky stuff!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure it's really something you'd ever guess without being told, but Applescript has its own [Date class](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/beginning-applescript/9780764574009/9780764574009_the_date_class.html) which means the quotes are not required. It will report like a string, but you don't need to refer to it as one.

So all you need is this…

```
set currentDay to weekday of (current date)

if currentDay = Monday or currentDay = Tuesday or currentDay = Wednesday then
    set earlymorningDisc to 1
else if currentDay = Thursday or currentDay = Friday then
    set earlymorningDisc to 2
else
    set earlymorningDisc to 3
end if
```

If you try this in the editor where you can see the Result in the lower pane

```
set currentDay to weekday of (current date)
return currentDay
```

You'll see it responds with `Friday`

whereas if you try

```
set currentDay to weekday of (current date) as string
return currentDay
```

You'll see it now responds with `"Friday"` in quotes.

BTW, you can concatenate your multiple ifs, rather than

```
if currentDay = Monday or currentDay = Tuesday or currentDay = Wednesday
```

you can use a list…

```
if currentDay is in {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday}
```

Comment: Welcome. Check my later addition too, which I was probably still typing as you posted, so you wouldn't see it. You can shorten to a list to reduce repetition.